# High memory usage of WordPress hosted on DreamHost VPS

Tags: memory, wordpress, dreamhost

Recently I see very high memory usage on VPS servers hosting my blog at DreamHost. There is not traffic increase in the recent months, but the memory usage is pushed by 250 MB. I tried looking at most frequently visited IPs in access.log files. But no clues. Can someone help me to find out the cause for high memory usage?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a problem with your memory usage, almost all is below 100 MB, the yellow line (cached memory), is not to be worried about. What is does is it leaves certain things in the memory or pre-fetches them because it anticipates the use of those items. If your memory is really needed it will remove those cached contents.
It is to make your system faster and it's not to be worried about.