# nginx VPS on Dreamhost using a lot of memory for two small sites

Tags: nginx, memory, vps, dreamhost

I have a similar problem to that of the user who posted [High memory usage of WordPress hosted on DreamHost VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/366205/high-memory-usage-of-wordpress-hosted-on-dreamhost-vps). The reason this is a 'problem' is because when it maxes out the memory quota I set for my VPS it will begin serving 503 error pages for 'uncached' pages (I guess?). Setting the quota higher does help, but I thought nginx would save me some money as well as provide better performance and less memory usage than Apache (especially) and lighttpd. One of my sites is simply an HTML-only website, and the other is a Wordpress website almost nobody looks at / extremely low traffic. I don't get it. I have the quota set to something like 512MB or 640MB RAM just to have it running decently.

**Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could do to make nginx run more efficiently, or why I am having this problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: And how did you tune nginx and PHP?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't do much. I got a VPS without Apache, and installed nginx just like that via SSH and root.

Answer (score 1):

You must put all domains under the same ftp user, like they say in the wiki.

> When using Nginx a set number of PHP processes are started up for every user a domain is hosted under. The same number are started regardless of how many domains are hosted for it. As such, if you have **10 domains spread across 10 separate FTP users** you'll get 10x as many PHP processes as you would otherwise get. So, **if Nginx is starting up 5 PHP processes**, you would end up with **50**, **which would eat up a considerable amount of memory**. The best configuration when using Nginx is to consolidate your domains under one FTP user. **You should definitely do this prior to switching to Nginx**.

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Nginx